# Is there a word for a divorced father who you don't live with?

Tags: word-choice

If your parents are divorced and you live with your mother, not your father, what would you call your father?

Comment: Your father? By not living with someone, the term father does not change, the feeling may but not the term

Comment: What? Wait... what?

Comment: Separated father ?

Comment: If I was the father, I'd hope it was 'Dad'.

Comment: Personally, I’d call him _Kelly_, ’cause that happens to be his name. But most would probably go with _dad_ or something similar.

Comment: Welcome @user128019. Do you want a way to *address* your father, or a way to *refer* to him?

Answer (score 7):

Your "non-custodial parent," is the one you don't live with. Most children of divorce, that live with their mothers, call this person "Dad". (US)

Comment: P.S. Or, in a formal setting, you can describe him to a third-party as 'my father'.  If you want to emphasise some ill-feeling then you could use the term, 'my estranged father'. https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=estranged+definition

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent#Biological_parents_and_parental_testing), when speaking of your father with others you could refer to him as

- my father
- my biological father

> The term **biological parent** refers to a parent who is the biological mother or father of an individual. While an individual's parents are often also their biological parents, it is seldom used unless there is an explicit difference between who acted as a parent for that individual and the person from whom they inherit half of their genes. **For example, a person whose father has remarried may call his new wife their stepmother and continue to refer to their mother normally, though someone who has had little or no contact with their biological mother may address their foster parent as their mother, and their biological mother as such, or perhaps by her first name.**